# dotnet publish command not working with asp dotnet project in aws buildspecs.yml file

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have created sample dot net application, folder structure as follows.

[image]

When i am using this command 
`dotnet publish -c release -o ./build_output demorepo2.csproj` build output is getting created inside `build_output` folder correctly.

Now i have another asp.net mvc web application.
[image]

Now i am using same command `dotnet publish -c release -o ./build_output test1.csproj` but this not working. Getting the following error.

[image]

Any idea why this error?

Answer (score 1):

From [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Command Line Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment)

Try to run this command:

```
msbuild demorepo2.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyPublishProfile
```

Comment: thanks for a quick reply. But why 'dotnet publish' command working in 1st case and failing in 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find Microsoft.WebApplication.targets file in specified path.

You need to find this file in your C: directory and set the path in .csproj file.

For example:

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="true" />
```